# Does Sqlite support weak entities?

Tags: sqlite

Does Sqlite support weak entities or tables that have a composite key where a number of foreign keys make up the primary key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can follow the following links regarding your doubts:

http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_composite

Answer (score 2):

Sqlite does support composite keys.

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html